# Primes with prescribed digits in two bases

Tags: analytic-number-theory

A result of Harman and Katai tells us that if $n$ is large, and $A$ is a subset of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ is of size $|A|=r<c \sqrt{n}/\log n$, then the number of primes up to $N=2^n$ with the $j$-th binary coefficients being prescribed is about $2^{-r} N/\log N$. See [Bourgain](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0398v1.pdf) for recent developments.

My question is whether one can do a similar result with two bases; namely, to simultaneously prescribe some of the coefficients, say, in both the binary expansion and the ternary expansion?